Can I access the NMEA messages using raw_gnss package on Flutter?
For one of my projects, I am trying to access the GNSS NMEA messages using a Flutter app in my Pixel 5. The library I am using right now is raw_gnss (https://github.com/deven98/raw_gnss). I could access the measurements data using the package but no clue on how to extract the NMEA messages.
Can anyone help me access the NMEA messages?
Thank you.
I tried different things with the gnssStatusModel, gnssMeasurementModel and raw_gnss functions but only gnssMeasurement model is working right now. I need to parse the raw NMEA messages with timestamp, constelliationType, svid, az, el and CN_0.
The main.dart file for gnssMeasurementModel (working):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/gnss_measurement_model.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/gnss_status_model.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/raw_gnss.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Eddy's GNSS logs"),
        ),
        body: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var _hasPermissions = false;
  late RawGnss _gnss;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _gnss = RawGnss();

    Permission.location
        .request()
        .then((value) => setState(() => _hasPermissions = value.isGranted));
  }




// Measurment Model

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _hasPermissions
      ? StreamBuilder<GnssMeasurementModel>(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null){
                    int count =0;
                    while(count< snapshot.data!.measurements!.length) {
                      return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        //"${snapshot.data!.status![count].svid} ${snapshot.data!.status![count].azimuthDegrees} ${snapshot.data!.status![count].elevationDegrees}"),
                        "Time: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].receivedSvTimeNanos} PRN: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].svid}, C_N0: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].cn0DbHz}, Constellation type: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].constellationType} "),
                    );
                    }
                  }
                },
              
                //itemCount: snapshot.data!.satelliteCount ?? 0,
              );
            
            },
          stream: _gnss.gnssMeasurementEvents,
        )
      : _loadingSpinner();

  Widget _loadingSpinner() => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

}

The main.dart for gnssStatusModel (not working):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/gnss_measurement_model.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/gnss_status_model.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/raw_gnss.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Eddy's GNSS logs"),
        ),
        body: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var _hasPermissions = false;
  late RawGnss _gnss;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _gnss = RawGnss();

    Permission.location
        .request()
        .then((value) => setState(() => _hasPermissions = value.isGranted));
  }


//GNSS STATUS 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _hasPermissions
      ? StreamBuilder<GnssStatusModel>(//StreamBuilder<GnssMeasurementModel>(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null){
                    int count =0;
                    while(count<snapshot.data!.status!.length){//while(count< snapshot.data!.measurements!.length) {
                      return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "${snapshot.data!.status![count].svid} ${snapshot.data!.status![count].azimuthDegrees} ${snapshot.data!.status![count].elevationDegrees}"),
                        //"Time: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].receivedSvTimeNanos} PRN: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].svid}, C_N0: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].cn0DbHz}, Constellation type: ${snapshot.data!.measurements![count].constellationType} "),
                    );
                    }
                  }
                },
              
                //itemCount: snapshot.data!.satelliteCount ?? 0,
              );
            
            },
          stream: _gnss.gnssStatusEvents,
        )
      : _loadingSpinner();

  Widget _loadingSpinner() => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}


I'm not an expert on the subject, but I had the same problem as you. I found that when the page is not tracking gnssMeasurement, the gnssStatus is never updated. As long as the gnssMeasurement value is tracked on the page, the gnssStatus is just as capable of changing as the gnssMeasurement.
You can try the following code, by default gnssMeasurement is not tracked, gnssStatus will always be realizing that it is loading, and once the Toggle GnssMeasurement button is clicked to show content related to gnssMeasurement, gnssStatus will be updated accordingly.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:raw_gnss/raw_gnss.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.lightGreen),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  var _hasPermissions = false;
  var _showGnssMeasurement = false;
  late RawGnss _gnss;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _gnss = RawGnss();

    Permission.location
        .request()
        .then((value) => setState(() => _hasPermissions = value.isGranted));
  }

  void _toggleGnssMeasurement() {
    setState(() {
      _showGnssMeasurement = !_showGnssMeasurement;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text("GnssStatus Demo"),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: !_hasPermissions
                ? const Text('No permissions!')
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: _gnss.gnssStatusEvents,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return const Text("Loading gnssStatus...");
                          }
                          var gnssStatus = snapshot.data!;
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Text('Update at : ${DateTime.now()}'),
                              Text(
                                  "All satellites: ${gnssStatus.satelliteCount}"),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      // 分隔线
                      const Divider(),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: _toggleGnssMeasurement,
                          child: const Text("Toggle GnssMeasurement")),
                      !_showGnssMeasurement
                          ? Container()
                          : StreamBuilder(
                              stream: _gnss.gnssMeasurementEvents,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return const Text(
                                      "Loading gnssMeasurement...");
                                }
                                var measurements = snapshot.data!.measurements!;
                                var lens = measurements.length;
                                return Text("Measurements lens: $lens");
                              })
                    ],
                  )));
  }
}

